# Regular Expression for eMail Service Provider

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm using Oracle 11.g.  I want to create a virtual column so that I can find out just the eMail service provider from an email address.  For example, I'd like the new column to display "verizon.net" based on the column eMailAddress containing "john.smith@verizon.net"  I think I need a regular expression to find everything after the "@" in the eMailAddress column.  I don't think 11.g supports lookahead.  How would I construct a regular expression for this?
Thanks for looking at this.

```
Select regexp_substr(email_address, '@([[:alnum:]]+\.?){1,2}/?') 
From mail_recipient 
Where prim_key = 1;
```

The actual code to produce a virtual column is below:

```
Alter Table mail_recipient
  Add (EMAIL_PROVIDER VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
    Generated Always As 
    (regexp_substr(email_address, '@([[:alnum:]]+\.?){1,2}/?')) VIRTUAL);
```

Comment: The above code seems to produce the expected results, but I'm not sure if I've constructed an overly complex regular expression.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to allow "-" and "_" in the names? On the other hand, why allow an optional "/" at the end? I think "ver-iz_on.com" would not match your regex but should. Also "verizon" (note the lack of ".") has several match options (wastes time). More efficient would be `@([[:alnum:]_-]+(\.[[:alnum:]_-]+){0,1})`, untested. That has only one way to match "verizon" and one for "verizon.com" (like yours). How about "@post.another.com" (note the two dots), should that match? I think it would not, at least not including the ".com". Would you like to add a word-end anchor ("\b" or something)?

Comment: With the info I can create a tested answer. You might want to provide more sample input and desired output, i.e. more diverse examples of names you want matched and not matched. Let me know whether perl regex flavor is OK, I am unfamiliar with your environment. Sed, grep, egrep would also be available to me.

Comment: Hello Yunnosch.  Thanks very much for replying.  I appreciate your suggestions very much.  This is an implementation of Oracle 11.g.  I don't think Perl is applicable.  This code is to get the domain for any type of eMail address.  So I'd want this to work for something complicated like: john.smith@domain1.domain2.domainX.com.  How do I capture everything after the at sign "@" in any type of email address?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: According to you, your code works. You just want inefficiencies spotted. I did and described them. I also mentioned examples of correct mail addresses which would probably not match. Wouldn't you like to test that and maybe update the code in your question accordingly? Otherwise state whether the ideas are applicable, then I would create a corresponding answer. How about more diverse sample input, for both outcomes, match desired and match undesired?

Comment: Hi Hunnosch.  I had indeed implemented your suggestion as soon as I read it.  It works fine in SQL Developer, my Oracle development tool and in the application.  Sorry if I didn't indicate that.  My question now is how to handle multiple sub-domains after the "@".  I have only 587 rows right now, and most seem to be rather simple eMail addresses of only one domain: "name@domain.top_level_domain".  When I create a test eMail address of "john.smith@domain1.domain2.domainx.com" the function using your suggested code returns only "@domain1.domain2" not all of "@domain1.domain2.domainx.com".

Comment: That is what I asked you. Do you know the `{0,1}` syntax? Try to increase the 1 to the number of dot-somethings you want, `{0,}` for indefinite.

Comment: Hello Hunnosch.  No, I did not know the {0,1} syntax.  Using {0,} did the trick.  The resulting code works perfectly.  Thanks very much for all your help.  Select regexp_substr(email_address, '@([[:alnum:]_-]+(\.[[:alnum:]_-]+){0,})') 
From mail_recipient 
Where prim_key = 121;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after some feedback iterations, this is what solves OPs problem:

```
 '@([[:alnum:]_-]+(\.[[:alnum:]_-]+){0,})'
```

- match more "tightly" to reduce extensive backtracking
- additionally allow "[_-]"
- additionally allow any number of ".blabla"